# Lost original prospectus for a Canadian mutual fund I bought. Where can I find another copy?

Tags: canada, mutual-funds

I had purchased a Canadian [Labour Sponsored Investment Fund (LSIF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labour_Sponsored_Venture_Capital_Corporation) back in 2001 – a terrible, *terrible* idea, and I've learned my lesson well since then.  The underlying investments were awful, and the fees worse.

Anyway, at that time, my broker had sent me a copy of the original **mutual fund prospectus** document.  I'm interested in having a look at that document again, but sadly, I cannot locate the original.

Is there a place where I can get a copy of the original prospectus for a Canadian mutual fund?  Is there an orgnanization that holds an archive of historical mutual fund documents?

I already tried [SEDAR](http://www.sedar.com), where I have found public company information before, but I had no luck finding the fund information.

I also tried the fund company (which has changed 3 times, owing to fund or company mergers) but their web site has nothing going back that far.

Comment: I wonder if you could get most of the same information from the current annual report?  Or do you want to see what they promised you at the time you originally invested?

Comment: @poolie It's your second point: A case of seeing what they promised originally, hence the interest in the historical report.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I came upon this question while searching through money.SE, and I'm poking around trying to find some info. Unfortunately my preliminary searching mostly leads me back to... this question. Do you still have the ticker of the fund? Was it listed on TSX?

Comment: It wasn't exchange-listed. For what it's worth, I no longer need an answer on this.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Ah, ok. I work with someone who used to be on the board of TMX group, so I figured if it was exchange-listed I could bother him about it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you tried this, but if you still have a full-service broker, you could ask them to find it for you.

In the US, Edgar would be right source for this, but I'm not sure about a Canadian issuance.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I hadn't forgot about my discount broker, but I know they will charge me a fee for this.  The last time I asked them retrieve some antique documentation (for a shareholder class action lawsuit), it cost me ~$100.  Ironically, after lawyers fees, etc. I recovered barely more than that amount from the class action :-/

Comment: BTW, **SEDAR** is the Canadian equivalent to EDGAR.